# В чём различия между die() и exit() в PHP?

Tags: php

В чём заключаются различия между функциями `die()` и `exit()` в PHP?

Comment: Вопрос минусовать не надо, минусовать надо ответ, если с ним не согласны.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет никакой разницы, `die` и `exit` — эквивалентные конструкции.

---

*`die` — псевдоним `exit` для пользователей пришедших из Perl.*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Оно и понятно, парсер парсит оба токена одинаково: [php-src](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_language_scanner.l#L1374-L1380)

Answer (score -1):

Хотя функции `die()` и `exit()` действительно эквивалентны и в PHP прекращают выполнение текущего скрипта, в них есть кардинальное отличие:

- `die()` **закрывает** соединение;
- `exit()` **не закрывает**    соединение.

---

**Пример:**

`die()`:

```
<?php
    header('HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified');
    die();
?>
```

`exit()`:

```
<?php
    header('HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified');
    exit();
?>
```

---

**Ответ сервера:**

`exit()`:

```
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 
Connection: Keep-Alive 
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
```

`die()`:

```
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 
Connection: close
```

Comment: А в документации написано, что они эквивалентны. Врут?

Comment: А где связь между PHP и HTTP-соединением?